# Should my headline be conversational, or stick to the numbers?

Tags: usability, gui-design, accessibility, ux-writing

which of these two options is easier and clearer for the user to understand and consume?

**Option 1:**

[image: First option: shows exercise price and exercisable shares side-by-side.]

**Option 2:**

[image: Second option: Says, You have 1,840 options available to exercise at 0.64/share]

Comment: I much prefer option 2 for understanding what I can do. But option 1 is easier to translate and to add iconography to.

Comment: How about both, labeled value plus a text description?

Comment: Both are OK, this should be solved by real user testing

Comment: I found option 2 easier to understand. After understanding what I was looking at, then option 1 made a little more sense.  I'm not sure I followed why 500 grants at £0.64/share comes out to GBP 400 instead of 320. Once you have a design, then I can comment on the accessibility of the option.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends entirely on who you are building this for and how this is being used. The first option allows for quick scanning labels and values. For people who use it often this can be very helpful. Showing it with labels and values aligned evenly (like a list/grid/table) will make this experience even better.

The second option is more explanatory and looks relevant for people not dealing with this kind of information constantly or who are dealing with cognitive limitations.

Since you tagged this question with accessibility there is a third option: Provide both. Show the label/value variant and provide a (collapsable) help section below for people who want/need it explained. When you use the right labeling and techniques for this, this can be made very accessible. It goes beyond the question to talk about techniques but as a hint you can look at [`aria-describedby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-describedby).

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is much easier to understand as its narrated well. You might consider using the same term either grants or options so it's easier to recognize than to recall.